# jQuery .each function loop through JSON nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have been having hard times trying to get to one specific key/value which is nested into JSON objects

This is the API response

```json
   response: {

    estabelecimento: {

      atividades_secundarias: [{
          id: "6209100",
          secao: "J",
          divisao: "62",
          grupo: "62.0",
          classe: "62.09-1",
          subclasse: "6209-1/00",
          descricao: "Suporte",
          contribuinte: false
        },

        {
          id: "7020400",
          secao: "M",
          divisao: "70",
          grupo: "70.2",
          classe: "70.20-4",
          subclasse: "7020-4/00",
          descricao: "Atividades",
          contribuinte: false
        },

        {
          id: "8211300",
          secao: "N",
          divisao: "82",
          grupo: "82.1",
          classe: "82.11-3",
          subclasse: "8211-3/00",
          descricao: "Serviços",
          contribuinte: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The GOAL is to return all descricao items from atividades_secundarias object and store them as a string?

In this case: "Suporte / Atividades / Servicos" ... something like this

Following are the things I have tried:

- Accessing `descricao` value by key string

```js
$.each(response.estabelecimento.atividades_secundarias,function(index, item) {
     $.each(index, function (key, val) {
         console.log(val["descricao"]);
     });
});
```

- Accessing `descricao` value using `this` operator

```js
$.each(response.estabelecimento.atividades_secundarias, function(index, item) {
     $.each(index.id, function (key, val) {
         console.log(this.descricao);
     });
});
```

I believe it's something very subtle I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.map()` to iterate through `atividades_secundarias`.

**Figure I**

```js
//    ⬇️ This is the path to "atividades_secundarias"   ⬇️
$.map(data.response.estabelecimento.atividades_secundarias, function(x, i) { 
//                                  "x" will be the current object ↗️
```

On each iteration, use `Object.keys()` on each object (call each object `x`) within the array. You'll get an array of each object's keys.

**Figure II**

```js
Object.keys(x) /* [ "id", "secao", "divisao", "grupo", "classe", "subclasse", 
"descricao", "contribuinte" ] *///An array of keys from each object
```

Next find the key `descricao` in each object with `.includes()` and return it's value `x.descricao` OR `null` if the object doesn't have that particular key.

**Figure III**

```js
/* [...<<array of keys>>]*/.includes('descricao') /* if "descricao" is
found...*/ ? /* return it's value */ x.descricao /* Otherwise return */
: null
```

`$.map()` returns an array so if you want a string simply use `.join()`.

**Figure IV**

```js
/*...*/ ).join('/') // "Suporte/Atividades/Serviços"
```

```js
const data = {
  response: {
    estabelecimento: {
      atividades_secundarias: [{
        id: "6209100",
        secao: "J",
        divisao: "62",
        grupo: "62.0",
        classe: "62.09-1",
        subclasse: "6209-1/00",
        descricao: "Suporte",
        contribuinte: false
      }, {
        id: "7020400",
        secao: "M",
        divisao: "70",
        grupo: "70.2",
        classe: "70.20-4",
        subclasse: "7020-4/00",
        descricao: "Atividades",
        contribuinte: false
      }, {
        id: "8211300",
        secao: "N",
        divisao: "82",
        grupo: "82.1",
        classe: "82.11-3",
        subclasse: "8211-3/00",
        descricao: "Serviços",
        contribuinte: false
      }]
    }
  }
};

const descricaos = $.map(data.response.estabelecimento.atividades_secundarias, function(x, i) {
  return Object.keys(x).includes('descricao') ? x.descricao : null;
}).join('/');

console.log(descricaos);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array of "descricao" values, you can simply do this:

```
let descricaoItemsArr = [];
$.each(response.estabelecimento.atividades_secundarias, function(index, item) {
  descricaoItemsArr.push(item.descricao);
});
```

You don't need a second $.each loop.

Comment: This is the only way to iterate through its values?

Comment: You can also do this with forEach or for...in, but if you are asking for a different way to access to that field, you can do response.estabelecimento.atividades_secundarias[index]['descricao']